# Read media-type (CD-R, CD-RW, DVD, BD etc) with Java

Tags: java, disk, volume

How can I programmatically (Java) get the media-type (CD-R, CD-RW, DVD-R, DVD-RW, BD etc) of a disk inserted in a disk-drive.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with native Java APIs, but there is a Delphi tutorial [here](http://www.delphipraxis.net/30772-cd-medien-erkennen.html), which provides enought code to write a JNI (or JNA) layer to extract this information at least on windows.